# In which Joomla DB table I could see information about website installation, such as name, domain, etc.?

Tags: database, joomla

My account is deactivated by my hosting provider because it got spammed by a bot. I need to uninstall few Joomla installations and I am trying to see only by looking at the database which one is which. They all are names website_jml1, website_jml2.. etc. Which table should I look into to quickly identify installations? In other words - where in DB joomla stores information about website domain, title, name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of all separate extension records, have a look in the `#__extensions` database table. Do bare in mind that each extension may have it's own separate database tables, so if you do plan on removing manually from the database, make sure you remove all associated database tables, along with files/folders from the Joomla directory.

Just on a side note, in future, **always** ensure you are running the latest version of Joomla, along with the extensions that you have on your site. Outdated extensions can lead to issues like the one you have.